# sbt project cannot find ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

Using  sbt to test the code

```
package examples
import org.specs2._

class ScalaCheckExamplesSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is = s2"""
  startsWith ${ prop { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b) must startWith(a) } }
  endsWith   ${ prop { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b) must endWith(b) } }
  substring  ${ prop { (a: String, b: String) => (a+b).substring(a.length) === b } }
  substring  ${ prop { (a: String, b: String, c: String) => (a+b+c).substring(a.length, a.length+b.length) === b } }                                                                                                                       """
}
```

with sbt configuration:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.5" % "test",
    "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.4" % "test"
)
```

the class `ScalaCheck` cannot be found:

```
ScalaCheckExamplesSpec.scala:11: not found: type ScalaCheck
[error] class ScalaCheckExamplesSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Are you using scala 2.12?

Comment: Using version 2.11.6, but it is not specified in build.sbt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.5" % "test",
  // the scalacheck lib will come as a transitive
  // dependency
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "3.8.5" % "test"
)
```

Comment: with `scalaVersion := "2.12.0"` in build.sbt , is needed to use version `3.8.6` in stead of version `3.8.5`